# Unitary representations of Kähler groups deformable to one another as complex representations

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, kahler-manifolds

Let $G=\pi_1(M)$ be the fundamental group of a compact Kähler manifold. Let $n$ be a non-negative integer. Then the set of homomorphisms $G\to GL(n, \mathbb{C})$ can be considered as a real variety $X$. The set of homomorphisms $G\to U(n)$ can be considered as a subvariety $X'\subset X$. Are there examples where two distinct connected components of $X'$ are contained in the same connected component of $X$ (in the analytic topology)?

Comment: $U(n)$ is not a subvariety of the complex variety $GL(n)$, and for the same reason $X'$ is not a subvariety of the complex variety $X$. However you can view $X$ as real variety ("Weil restriction"), or rather as real points of some suitably defined variety, and then $\mathrm{Hom}(G,U(n))$ is Zariski closed in it. Then your question has two possible interpretations, because the connected components of $X'$ for the ordinary and for the Zariski topology do usually not coincide. (Alternatively you can view $X'$ as set of real points of the complex variety defining $X'$, rather than subvariety.)

Comment: But the other mistake is the bare meaning of subvariety. If you want to view $X'$ as subvariety, you need to view $X$ as real variety (of dimension twice its complex dimension). In the complex Zariski topology, $X'$ is probably Zariski dense in $X$ in many cases.